# JavaScript Array in function using DOM and appendChild

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, button

I have a problem with my simple script for adding questions and answers. More specifically, with the addition of further answers to the following questions the second question continues the naming of the answer from where the first one stopped - e.g.

Question 1
answers
a,b,c

Question 2
answers
a,b,**d**

I think I have to use an array, every question -> own array.

```js
  n = 1;

  function add_question() {

    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "question[" + n + "]";
    textarea.className = "form-control";
    textarea.id = "pytanie_id_" + n;
    textarea.name = "data[" + n + "][pytanie]";
    textarea.autocomplete = "off";
    var addone = document.createElement("input");
    addone.type = "button";
    addone.value = "+";
    addone.id = "id_" + n;
    addone.className = "btn  btn-success-my";
    addone.innerHTML = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\">";
    var label_pyt = document.createElement("label");
    label_pyt.className = "col-md-4 control-label";
    label_pyt.for = "pytanie_id_" + n;
    label_pyt.innerHTML = "Question " + n + ".";
    var label_odp_a = document.createElement("label");
    label_odp_a.className = "col-md-4 control-label";
    label_odp_a.for = "odp_a_id_" + n;
    label_odp_a.innerHTML = " A";
    var input_odp_a = document.createElement("input");
    input_odp_a.id = "odp_a_id_" + n;
    input_odp_a.name = "data[" + n + "][odp_a]";
    input_odp_a.type = "text";
    input_odp_a.className = "form-control input-md";
    input_odp_a.autocomplete = "off";
    var label_odp_b = document.createElement("label");
    label_odp_b.className = "col-md-4 control-label";
    label_odp_b.for = "odp_b_id_" + n;
    label_odp_b.innerHTML = " B";
    var input_odp_b = document.createElement("input");
    input_odp_b.id = "odp_b_id_" + n;
    input_odp_b.name = "data[" + n + "][odp_b]";
    input_odp_b.type = "text";
    input_odp_b.className = "form-control input-md";
    input_odp_b.autocomplete = "off";
    //addone.addEventListener("onclick", function(n){add_answer(n);});
    var divquest = document.createElement("div");
    divquest.id = "us_pytanie_" + n;
    divquest.innerHTML = "<div class=\"form-group\"> <hr>" + label_pyt.outerHTML 
              + "<div class=\"col-md-4\"> " + textarea.outerHTML 
                        + "</div></div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" 
                        + label_odp_a.outerHTML + "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" 
                        + input_odp_a.outerHTML 
                        + "</div></div>" 
                        + "<div class=\"form-group\">" 
                        + label_odp_b.outerHTML 
                        + "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" 
                        + input_odp_b.outerHTML 
                        + "</div></div>" 
                        + "<div id=\"radiodown" + n + "\" ></div>" 
                        + "<div class=\"form-group\">" 
                        + "<label class=\"col-md-4 control-label\"> </label>" 
                        + "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" 
                        + "<div class=\"btn-group btn-group-justified\">" 
                        + "<div class=\"btn-group\">" 
                        + addone.outerHTML 
                        + "</div>"
                        + "<div class=\"btn-group\">" 
                        + "</div>" 
                        + "</div>" 
                        + "</div>" 
                        + "</div>" 
                        + "</div></div>";
    document.getElementById("question").appendChild(divquest);
    var btn = document.getElementById("id_" + n);
    if (btn.addEventListener) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        add_answer(this);
      });
    } else if (btn.attachEvent) { // IE < 9 :(
      btn.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
        add_answer(this);
      });
    }
    n++;
  }

  abc_index = 0;

  function add_answer(index) {
    //alert("called"+(this).id);
    index = index.id.split("_")[1];
    var abc_table_answer = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
      abc_table_answer[x] = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    }
    var abc_table_db_answer = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
      abc_table_db_answer[x] = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    }
    //alert(abc_index + index);
    var option = document.createElement("input");
    option.id = "odp_" + abc_table_db_answer[index][abc_index] + "_id_" + index + "";
    option.name = "data[" + index + "][odp_" + abc_table_db_answer[index][abc_index] + "]";
    option.type = "text";
    option.className = "form-control input-md";
    option.autocomplete = "off";
    var label_option = document.createElement("label");
    label_option.className = "col-md-4 control-label";
    label_option.for = "odp_" + abc_table_db_answer[index][abc_index] + "_id_" + index + "";
    label_option.innerHTML =  abc_table_answer[index][abc_index] + "";
    var optiondiv = document.createElement("div");
    optiondiv.id = "us_answer_" + index + "_" + abc_index + "";
    optiondiv.className = "form-group";
    optiondiv.innerHTML = label_option.outerHTML + "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" + option.outerHTML + "</div></div>";
    document.getElementById("radiodown" + index).appendChild(optiondiv);
    abc_index++;
  }
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="ADD" onclick="add_question();" />
<br/><br/>
<div id="question"></div><br/>
```

However, the following questions do not use separate tables, and here comes the problem.

Please tell me if there is a solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Also add jsfiddle

[jsfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Karol81628/t8ufkapa/)

Comment: try making a code pen.

Comment: @KarolNiedźwiedź - what is the expected output that you have problems with? The code creates questions and you want to create the answers in another way? Also change `type="submit" ` to `type="button"`

Comment: @mplungjan : I couldn't see the "code snippet" from ios app..

Comment: Also why not have the question and answer in the form you want in a hidden HTML div and then clone and just change the numbering?

Comment: @mplungjan The problem is the order of the tags (A, B, C) (A, B, D) you must test the "code snipped"

Comment: See my update to your question - it is now much clearer. Create an object `{ q1 :  {a:"",b:"",c:""}, q2 : {a:"",b:"",c:"",d:""}}`

Comment: @mplungjan Ok but how do you dynamically move to the next element of the object? In my case, I would like to add another answer to the next element (a, b, c ...) so much that I do not know how many questions can be.

Comment: `qObject[qName]={}; qObject[qName][answerName]="..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Demo Outline

#### Problem

OP expected behavior for adding extra answers to a list.

2. question

   a. answer

   b. answer

   c. answer

   d. answer <--appended to list

This is the actual behavior:

2. question

   a. answer

   b. answer

   c. answer

   e. answer <--appended to list because Question 1 has `d. answer`

Because the form is driven by events from user interaction (i.e. clicking buttons), loops and arrays aren't totally necessary. If this project was to use data from a dynamic source later on, arrays and loops should be considered.

#### Demo Outline

1. `base()` function creates several base elements (which is the the layout part that isn't duplicated), and sets required attributes.
2. All elements are appended to a `documentFragment` and that in turn is appended to the DOM.
3. The procedure described in #1 and #2 is prefered because running anything in DOM requires more work for the browser.
4. After loading, the layout has a `<fieldset>` with the form fields on the left and on the right is an iframe. Its purpose is to display the data submitted to a test server. **Note:** Due to SO sandbox, this feature does not function. Review this [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/P99h94m1a4EUmvxIfgyh/) for a fully functional demo.
5. Clicking the green <kbd>Add</kbd> button will append a **QA** (**Q**uestion and **A**nswers).
6. Clicking the blue <kbd>Submit</kbd> button does nothing in a SO Stack Snippet. (see #4)
7. The checkbox labeled **True/False** will hide 2 of the 4 answers to accomodate a question of a Boolean nature.
8. The plus <kbd>+</kbd> button will add an answer to the QA it belongs to.
9. All form control fields that carry data,(`<textarea>`, `<input>`), have a unique #id and [name].

**More details are commented in demo and references are located at the end of this post**

### Demo (See [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/P99h94m1a4EUmvxIfgyh/) for a functioning demo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title></title>
  <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    #quiz {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    section {
      order: 2
    }
    
    textarea {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .alpha {
      list-style: lower-alpha
    }
    
    li {
      margin: 0 0 10px 20px
    }
    
    .list-group-item-heading {
      margin-left: 0
    }
    /* When True/False checkbox is checked, 
    || the following rulesets are invoked 
    */
    
    .tf:checked+ol>li:last-of-type,
    .tf:checked+ol>li:nth-of-type(3) {
      display: none;
    }
    
    button,
    input[type=submit] {
      margin: 0 0 10px 0
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <script>
    var n = 0;
    /* Fastest way to use .createElement() and 
    || .appendChild() is to create a documentFragment,
    || append all elements to the fragment,
    || set attributes to the elements,
    || then append the documentFragment to the DOM
    */
    var base = function(n) {
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
      var quiz = document.createElement('form');
      var sec = document.createElement('section');
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      var sbt = document.createElement('input');
      var fSet = document.createElement('fieldset');
      var lgd = document.createElement('legend');
      var ol = document.createElement('ol');
      quiz.id = 'quiz';
      quiz.classList.add('container', 'form-group-lg');
      quiz.action = 'http://httpbin.org/post';
      quiz.method = 'post';
      quiz.target = 'view';
      sec.className = 'col-md-6';
      btn.id = 'add0';
      btn.type = 'button';
      btn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary', 'pull-right');
      sbt.type = 'submit';
      sbt.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success', 'pull-right');
      btn.textContent = 'Add';
      fSet.id = 'set0';
      fSet.classList.add("form-group", "col-md-6");
      lgd.textContent = "Quiz Template";
      ol.id = 'qa0';
      ol.className = 'list-group';
      frag.appendChild(quiz);
      quiz.appendChild(sec);
      fSet.appendChild(sbt);
      fSet.appendChild(btn);
      quiz.appendChild(fSet);
      fSet.appendChild(lgd);
      fSet.appendChild(ol);
      document.body.appendChild(frag);
      genQA(n, '#qa0');
      /* .insertAdjacentHTML() is .innerHTML on
      || steroids. 
      || Use this for complex layouts and elements that
      || are heavy with attributes
      */
      sec.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<iframe name='view' src='about:blank' width='100%' height='60%' frameborder='1'></iframe>");
    }

    var genQA = function(n, sel) {
      var dock = document.querySelector(sel);
      /* This is an ES6 Template Literal
      || It's a Literal String with a new powerful
      || syntax:
Wrap - LS: in quotes ' or " | TL: wrap in backticks `
Variables - LS: ' + var + ' | TL: ${var}
2+Lines - LS: + or \[enter] | TL: [enter]
      */
      var cFields = `
 <li class='list-group-item-heading'>
 <textarea id='q${n}' name="q${n}" rows='3' cols='25'></textarea>
 </li>
 <label>True/False</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class='tf checkbox-inline' type='checkbox'>
 
 <ol class='list-group alpha'>
 <li>
 <input id="a${n}_1" name="a${n}_1" type="text" class="input-md" autocomplete="off">
 </li>
 <li>
 <input id="a${n}_2" name="a${n}_2" type="text" class="input-md" autocomplete="off">
 </li>
 <li>
 <input id="a${n}_3" name="a${n}_3" type="text" class="input-md" autocomplete="off">
 </li>
 <li>
 <input id="a${n}_4" name="a${n}_4" type="text" class="input-md" autocomplete="off">
 </li>
 </ol>
 <label id='a${n}' class='btn btn-info ans'>&#65291;</label>
<hr>
`;

      dock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cFields);

    }
    // Invoked once per session
    base(n);

    /* Referencing form and its form control fields
    || using HTMLFormControlsCollection 
    */
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var field = form.elements;

    /* Register the click event on button#add0
    || invoke addQA() callback function
    */
    field.add0.addEventListener('click', addQA);

    /* Simple callback to generate a QA and 
    || increment counter
    */
    function addQA(e) {
      n++;
      genQA(n, '#qa0');
    }

    /* Register the click event on fieldset#set0
    || invoke the callback function addA()
    */
    field.set0.addEventListener('click', addA);

    function addA(e) {
      // if the node clicked has the .class '.ans'...
      if (e.target.classList.contains('ans')) {
        // Reference e.target by #id
        var tgt = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        // Get the main index (the number in its #id)
        var idx = parseInt(e.target.id.substring(1), 10);
        // Find the <ol> sibling preceding it (older bro)
        var list = tgt.previousElementSibling;
        /* Get the #id of the <ol>'s child's child
        || element (grandkid)
        */
        var last = list.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.id;
        // Get the last digit of its #id and increment it
        var jdx = parseInt(last.split('_').pop(), 10) + 1;
        /* This is a Template Literal of a list item and
        || input with interpolated #id and [name]
        */
        var li = `<li><input id="a${idx}_${jdx}" name="a${idx}_${jdx}" type="text" class="input-md" autocomplete="off"></li>`;
        // Append new list item to list
        list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
      }
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### References

- [**Template Literals**](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html)
- [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [**.insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641187/select-elements-of-html-table-and-change-contents-using-jquery/47641455#47641455)

Comment: You are very welcome. I thought it'd be easier too, but (happens often) I start thinking about how much layout change is realistic IRL or if a more generic approach will make a function reusable vs. efficiency and specialization, etc.