# Select elements of html table and change contents using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Professionals 
I have a table in my asp.net page

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
  <div class="agile-news-table">
    <div class="w3ls-news-result">
      <h4>Search Results : <span>25</span></h4>
    </div>
    <table id="table-breakpoint">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Album Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="w3-list-img">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/m1.jpg" alt="" /> <span>Al Muallim</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>2003</td>
          <td class="w3-list-info"><a href="comedy.html">Sami Yusuf</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="w3-list-img">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/m2.jpg" alt="" /> <span>Barakah</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>2017</td>
          <td class="w3-list-info"><a href="genre.html">Sami Yusuf</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

the table you see is an html template, it has 25 rows as you see in the `<span>` in the `<h4>` . 
I get data of Albums by ajax and I want by jQuery to assign the values in there palces in the table. 
I am using a loop on the 25 rows, and for every row I must reach the `<img>` in the second `<td>` to change its `src` , same for the `<spane>` beside it to change the text inside it which is the album name.
In the third `<td>` also to change the year in it .
In the forth `<td>` I need to change the `href` of `<a>` and the text of `<a>` which is the name of the artist. 
Do you see that `id="a"` in the first `<div>`, this is because I have like this table for every letter in the alphabet, where the letter is the `id` for that table, 
 and there is an A-ZList of the letters where a click on a letter wil make request to bring the albums with names start with the clicked letter, and assing them from the `XmlHttpRequest.responseText` to the table. 
Thats why I use `letter` variable in this jQuery code to pass the `id` of the first `<div>` to assign the values into the table , because there is another `<div id="b">` and so on

```js
function AssignAlbumIntoDOM(albumName, albumYear, albumPhotoPath, artistName, albumsCount, i, letter) {
  if (i < 25 && i >= 0) { // keep calling until i is 25
    jQuery("#" + letter + " h4 span").text(albumsCount);
    jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0).attr("src", albumPhotoPath);
    jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(2).text(albumYear);
    jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(3).children().eq(0).text(artistName);
  }
}
```

by the this code I can assing the `albumYear` in the third `<td>` and `artistName` in thr fourth `<td>`, 
 but could not change in the second `<td>` the `albumPhotoPath` in `<img>` `src` and the `albumName` in the `<span>`  
Can I extend the question 
This page as you see from the explanation, is a search page 
And I have all the information of the album except the songs of the album, so how can I pass these information to a page called `Single.aspx` dedcated to show an album information and its songs after clicking the `<img>` in the second `<td>`, and in the `Single.aspx` I only need by ajax to request the songs of the album not all the information again. 
I think the passing will be as a `QueryString` in the `href` of `<a>` in the second `<td>`, is there another way?

I thank you so much so much

Comment: The answer is un-deleted...I remember this one has a cool demo, happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed by the developer tools in Firefox that the javascript libraries in the html template are wrapping the the content of the second `<td>` in the table in a `<span>` that is why my first jQuery code did not work but after I modyfied it, it worked like this

```js
if (i < 25 && i >= 0) { // keep calling until i is 25 means i:[0-24]
  jQuery("#" + letter + " h4 span").text(albumsCount);
  jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0).children().eq(0).attr("src", albumPhotoPath);
  jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).children().eq(0).children().eq(1).text(albumName);
  jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(2).text(albumYear);
  jQuery("#" + letter + " table tbody").children().eq(i).children().eq(3).children().eq(0).text(artistName);
  //jQuery("#" + letter + " h4 span").text(albumsCount);
  //jQuery("#" + letter + "r" + (i + 1) + " td:eq(1) img").attr('src', albumPhotoPath);
  //jQuery("#" + letter + "r" + (i + 1) + " td:eq(1) a span").text(albumName);
  //jQuery("#" + letter + "r" + (i + 1) + " td:eq(2)").text(albumYear);
  //jQuery("#" + letter + "r" + (i + 1) + " td:eq(3) a").text(artistName);
}
```

here in the comments I tried Matt Spinks's answer with modification but I replaced `:nth-child(1-based index)` with `:eq(0-based index)`

Comment: There was an answer here from @zer00ne I did not read it, bet when I came back to read it, it is not found now

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to assign id's or indexes to your row objects in the dom and reference them that way. Something like this:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
  <div class="agile-news-table">
    <div class="w3ls-news-result">
      <h4>Search Results : <span>25</span></h4>
    </div>
    <table id="table-breakpoint">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Movie Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="w3-list-img">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/m1.jpg" alt="" /> <span>Al Muallim</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>2003</td>
          <td class="w3-list-info"><a href="comedy.html">Sami Yusuf</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="w3-list-img">
            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/m2.jpg" alt="" /> <span>Barakah</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>2017</td>
          <td class="w3-list-info"><a href="genre.html">Sami Yusuf</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, when loading the content, use the `nth-child` selector to target the specific table cell you want to populate:

```
function AssignAlbumIntoDOM(albumName, albumYear, albumPhotoPath, artistName, albumsCount, i, letter) {
  if (i < 25 && i >= 0) { // this raises some red flags. check your calling function. 
    jQuery("#" + letter + " h4 span").text(albumsCount);
    jQuery("#" + i + " td:nth-child(2) img").attr('src',albumPhotoPath);
    jQuery("#" + i + " td:nth-child(3)").html(albumYear);
    jQuery("#" + i + " td:nth-child(4)").html(artistName);
  }
}
```

I changed the index of `nth-child` because `<img>` is the second child because `nth-child` starts indexing from 1 not 0 
and `.text(albumsCount)` is not in side the table rows to use `i`

Comment: your idea of id is good , and easier but I have first to add ids to the html tags in the code, but I wanted to see the ability of jQuery and reach the rows depending on the id of the first `<div>` `id="a"` because I have 28 table wrapped in two divs like this `<div id="a"><div></div></div>` for every alphabet letter

Comment: you gave me the majority of knowledge of the answer using the id way but I still ask about the extension of my question to pass information to another page using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The question looks like it's all over the place so here's what I think you are asking:

> How do you display data in a HTML table?

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference to section "N"
var char = document.querySelector('section').id;
console.log(char);
// Counter
var index = 0;
// Object of arrays
var data = {
  url0: ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevermind', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Kingdom'],
  img: ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b7/NirvanaNevermindalbumcover.jpg', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9d/No_Doubt_-_Tragic_Kingdom.png'],
  album: ['NeverMind', 'Tragic Kingdom'],
  year: ['1991', '1995'],
  url1: ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(band)', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Doubt'],
  artist: ['Nirvana', 'No Doubt']
};
// Pass data
function DisplayAlbum(data) {
  // Reference the counter
  this.idx = index;
  // Object data property values by index
  this.url0 = data['url0'][index];
  this.img = data['img'][index];
  this.album = data['album'][index];
  this.year = data['year'][index];
  this.url1 = data['url1'][index];
  this.artist = data['artist'][index];
  /* Row is a Template Literal with all of
  || object data's values interpolated
  */
  this.row = `
  <tr>
  <td>${idx+1}</td>
  <td><a href="${url0}">
  <img src="${img}">
  ${album}</a>
  </td> 
  <td>${year}</td>
  <td><a href="${url1}">
  ${artist}</a>
  </td>
  </tr>`;
  index++;
  return this.row;
}
/* On button click append the return of
|| DisplayAlbum()
*/
$('#' + char + ' .btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#' + char + ' .table').append(DisplayAlbum(data));
});
```

```css
html {
  font: 100 10px/1 Consolas;
}

img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  font: inherit
}

td {
  text-align: center
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<section id="N" class='a-z'>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h4>Search Results:
        <output class='hits'></output>
      </h4>
      <button class='btn'>Add Row</button>
    </header>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Album</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne, it is a cool demo <br /> First, the object of arrays, data, how were they formed as an object of arrays, because I receive them at the client as a response text? <br /> Second, inside the function `DisplayAlbum(data)` what does `this` refer to? <br /> Third, what is this notation `${idx+1}`?

Comment: 1. The object of arrays is an example of data that is a result of a parsed JSON. Your question didn't provide an input so I guessed by how I saw your output resembled. 2. I had unconsciously made a constructor -_- and it worked 0_0! All functions are objects so this refers to itself, Google constructors it gets confusing... 3. That is Template Literal interpolation it's just like concatenating a string literal ex. `str="index: "+idx+1;` is the same as `str=\`index: ${idx+1}\``

Comment: Thank you very much @zer00ne, but if I am using an `SqlDataReader` to read the fields of Albums Table and appending them in a `StringBuilder` how can I in C# forming them as JSON object as the one you wrote

Comment: I'm merely front-end, and I don't know C#  I know  C and C++ marginally (apples and oranges) JSON is a very common format used between server and client. It's signature is almost identical to an object literal with the exception is that both key and value must be wrapped in double quotes" "